# Footwear-related tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Do we really need all the different tags for footwear? Most don't have definitions to help people decide which one to use (or how to choose more than one) - and I think, at the very least, [footwear](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/footwear) should absorb [footgear](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/footgear) as a synonym.

Comment: I am inclined to agree.